# Does successful return from typeid guarantee that dynamic_cast won't throw an exception?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, typeid

I am trying to decide how many places in my code I want to put try/catch blocks.

I have the following functions.

```
void bar(BaseType* basePtr)
{
   DerivedType* dTypePtr = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(basePtr);
   if ( NULL != dTypePtr )
   {
      // Do stuff.
   }
}

void Controller::foo()
{    
   std::vector<BaseType*>::iterator iter = this->bList.begin();
   std::vector<BaseType*>::iterator end = this->bList.end();
   for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
   {
      BaseType* basePtr = *iter;
      bool isObjectOK = true;

      // Check whether an object has been deleted without
      // notifying us.
      // If we can get the typeid of the object, chances are that
      // it has not been deleted.
      try
      {
         int const* typeName = typeid(*basePtr).name();
      }
      catch(...)
      {
         isObjectOK = false;
      }

      if ( isObjectOK )
      {
         bar(basePtr);
      }
   }
}
```

If I can successfully get a value from `typeid(*basePtr).name()`, can I safely assume that `dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(basePtr)` will not throw an exception? If not, I have to modify `bar` to:

```
void bar(BaseType* basePtr)
{
   DerivedType* dTypePtr = NULL;
   try
   {
      dTypePtr = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(basePtr);
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      // Drop the exception.
   }

   if ( NULL != dTypePtr )
   {
      // Do stuff.
   }
}
```

Comment: If you can't use `std::weak_ptr`, can you modify the destructor `~BasePtr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `basePtr` was a pointer to an object that has since been deleted, it is not "safe" or well-defined to do anything at all with that dangling pointer value.  `typeid(*basePtr)` and `dynamic_cast<T*>(basePtr)` are both undefined behavior, meaning the situation is worse than causing an exception: your program could crash, could do the wrong thing, or could appear to work for years and then suddenly break.

If you need to know about destruction of objects, this sounds like a case for `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`.  Ordinary code should not use new expressions or delete expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the requirements of the application, I can't use std::shared_ptr or std::weak_ptr. The real solution is for clients to notify `Controller` when a `BaseType` gets deleted. I'm trying to figure out how to detect those defects and deal with them as gracefully as I can.

Comment: Actually, `typeid(*p)` is always fine when the type pointed to by `p` is not polymorphic, since the standard says it is unevaluated in that case (so it's like `sizeof(*p)`). But according to people on the std-discussion mailing list, it is undefined behaviour when the type is polymorphic, for obvious reasons---the implementation has to examine the type of the object at runtime.

Comment: @Brian, are you saying that using `typeid(*p)`, where `p` is a pointer to a polymorphic type, will result in undefined behavior?

Comment: Make that "where `p` is a pointer to a polymorphic type that has been deleted".